# how to remove scrolling of the QComboBox element?

Tags: python, scroll, pyqt5, qcombobox

here is my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()

self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
self.comboBox.setStyleSheet('''
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}''')


self.comboBox.addItem("1")
self.comboBox.addItem("2")
self.comboBox.addItem("3")
self.comboBox.addItem("1")
self.comboBox.addItem("2")
self.comboBox.addItem("3")
self.comboBox.addItem("1")
self.comboBox.addItem("2")
self.comboBox.addItem("3")
self.comboBox.addItem("1")
self.comboBox.addItem("2")
self.comboBox.addItem("3")
self.comboBox.addItem("1")
self.comboBox.addItem("2")
self.comboBox.addItem("3")
self.comboBox.addItem("1")
self.comboBox.addItem("2")
self.comboBox.addItem("3")
self.comboBox.addItem("1")
self.comboBox.addItem("2")
self.comboBox.addItem("3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

but when I hover the mouse cursor over the place indicated by the red arrow, the list starts scrolling by itself

[image]

if from the QComboBox style

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

remove these two lines, then this scrolling disappears.
But I need to keep these two styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrolling behaviour can be switched off by [setting the auto-scroll property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#autoScroll-prop) of the view:

```
self.comboBox.view().setAutoScroll(False)
```